# Angular keep doing request with https

Tags: angular

I have an API with the url http://192.168.x.y:PORT. I changed the url to https://192.168.x.y:PORT (with http s) beacause i tried to use SSL in the server.

When I come back to the  old url (http://192.168.x.y:PORT, without http s and I remove the ssl cert in the server), Angular (8.2.12) keep doing request to the url with https.

````
@Injectable(
)
export class GenericProvider { 

    httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
  

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  public getArrayOfObject(uri: string): Observable<Object[]> {
    const url = AppSettings.URL_BASE + uri;
    return this.http.get<Object[]>(`${url}`);
  }
...
}```

And my AppModule:

```@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        LayoutModule,
        OverlayModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}```

Any help ? Thanks in advance !
````

Comment: hard to tell what you are asking. try doing a console log of your url and see if it is what you think it should be.

Comment: Angular changes the url to 'https://.....', this is what i don't understand. The error in the console is: zone-evergreen.js:2952 GET https://192.168.x.y:PORT/api/Pays net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Thanks for your response.

Comment: angular has no ability to "change a url". something else is going on. that's why I suggest you console.log the url to see if it is what you think it is.

Comment: Chrome does that, not angular. Try an incognito window..